# Warning: is_readable() expects parameter 1 to be a valid path

Tags: magento-1.9, bug, varien

I have been getting this error pointing to this function

```
protected function _checkSrcIsFile($src)
{
    $result = false;
    if (is_string($src) && is_readable($src) && is_file($src)) {
        $result = true;
    }

    return $result;
}
```

and the funtion is being passed here:

```
$srcIsFile = $this->_checkSrcIsFile($src);
if ($srcIsFile) {
    $src = realpath($src);
    $result = $this->cp($src, $filename);
} else {
    $result = $this->filePutContent($filename, $src);
}

if (!is_null($mode) && $result !== false) {
    $this->chmod($filename, $mode);
}

return $result;
```

can anyone explain to me what is causing this and what is the solution and how can I recreate it.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've you use an older Magento version (<1.9.3.1?) this seems to be a bug in Varian lib.

Current version supresses `is_readable` error (**@** is_readable())...<

```
protected function _checkSrcIsFile($src)
{
    $result = false;
    if (is_string($src) && @is_readable($src) && is_file($src)) {
        $result = true;
    }

    return $result;
}
```

**Edit:**

No, it is still there ... it's "fixed" only in LTS project ...

See https://github.com/OpenMage/magento-lts/pull/85

Instead of supreess error it should also work to check `if(file_exists($src))` before `is_readable().`

Comment: I am using Magento EE 1.14.xx and this is not helping the error is still there when I create invoices on the back end.